# Apply css for anchor tag inside li

Tags: html, css

I want to apply css to anchor tag which is inside li and li is inside ".whitedrop" class

```
    <ul class="dropdown whitedrop">
        <li><a>My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a>Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I tried,

```
    .whitedrop li a{
        background: red;
    }
```

But it is not working. What am i doing wrong here?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: [Nothing](http://jsfiddle.net/o13mL2am/), at least not in this fragment of code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ns1avr7p/  Its working Only Yaar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already working. [Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8uc19pd/).

Maybe there's another style with `background: none` interfering someway. Try to alter your CSS rule adding `!important` **just for test purposes** to confirm this behavior:

```
   .whitedrop li a{
        background: red !important;
    }
```

Also, it can be something related to browser cache. Did you try breaking the cache with a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in your Web browser tab?

Comment: @VijayakumarSelvaraj It should... Also it can be that OP thinks that the CSS file is loaded and forgot to add the link tag... who knows...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Actually it was browser cache

Comment: @ErmaIsabel Either if you're using Chrome or Firefox, do you know that you can disable browser cache from Developer Tools / Firebug?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer One more doubt. What should i do if i need to add css style for all li's except the last li

Comment: @ErmaIsabel You should do what you did, and add another style `.whitedrop li a:last-child` which invalidates the other styles. For example, if you added a background in the `.whitedrop li a` rule, in `.whitedrop li a:last-child` you should add `background: none`.

Comment: @ErmaIsabel 100% sure you're doing something wrong :D